# Resolving a "The program object is incomplete." opengl error

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I am currently programming on an Android application.

Here is my code:

```
program = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

System.out.println("Program: " + program);

GLES20.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
CustomRenderer.checkGlError("AttachingVertex");

GLES20.glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);
CustomRenderer.checkGlError("AttachingFragment");

GLES20.glLinkProgram(program);
CustomRenderer.checkGlError("LinkProgram");
System.out.println("Is Program: " + GLES20.glIsProgram(program));

GLES20.glValidateProgram(program);
System.out.println("Error log: " + GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(program));


GLES20.glUseProgram(program);
CustomRenderer.checkGlError("UseProgram");
```

And this is the output:

```
11-20 14:02:01.442: I/System.out(6370): Vertex: 1
11-20 14:02:01.442: I/System.out(6370): Is Shader: true
11-20 14:02:01.447: I/System.out(6370): Fragment: 2
11-20 14:02:01.447: I/System.out(6370): Is Shader: true
11-20 14:02:01.447: I/System.out(6370): Program: 3
11-20 14:02:01.447: I/System.out(6370): Is Program: true
11-20 14:02:01.447: I/System.out(6370): Error log: The program object is incomplete.
11-20 14:02:01.447: I/System.out(6370): UseProgram: glError 1282
```

You can also see the additional checks I did for the shaders, and they all seem to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this error message is that the Shaders did **not** compile! Despite 'being' shaders and having an id they did not compile.

Check if the shaders compiled with the `GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog` method. This will tell you what's wrong and you will have to fix that.

Comment: Part of the problem is you think `glIs___(...)` functions tell you anything about the validity of an OpenGL object. This is not the case, this simply tells you if the name (`GLuint` handle) is associated with that type of object. This association occurs the first time you bind a name to something (e.g. `glGenTextures (...)` will return a name, but that name is not actually a texture until you make a call like `glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, name)`). Even so, `glIsTexture (...)` will return `GL_TRUE` even if you have never done anything with that texture beyond simply binding it once.